# How to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 on dual boot PC?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my system. Windows 10 runs on SSD and Ubuntu runs on HDD.

Originally I created a 200 GB partition for Ubuntu. Now I want to format Ubuntu and install from scratch but I have important files on my HDD as well.

How can I just format that 200 GB Ubuntu partition and reinstall Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: you can remove Ubuntu partition and recreate another one of same size after; it can be a bit longer, but even simple and safer

Comment: if I did remember good, you can do it with the Ubuntu installer (with bootable USB for example)

Comment: You can format existing Ubuntu root partition during installation of new version using a bootable media. This is in the step where you allocate various Ubuntu partitions. Or you can format the Ubuntu root partition using Windows disk management.